# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 137]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, web-applications

I'm building a web app to make a model predict the User_input value (which in my case are 9 different sliders of the features contains different values) and to show the result and prediction accuracy at the end.
So when I try to predict the User_input instead of X_test I get this error :
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 137]

Here are the inputs I'm taking from the user :

```
def dataset_input(dataset_name):
inputs = dict()

user_input1=st.slider("Clump Thickness", 1, 10, step=1)
user_input2=st.slider("Uniformity of Cell Size", 1, 10, step=1)
user_input3=st.slider("Uniformity of Cell Shape", 1, 10, step=1)
user_input4=st.slider("Marginal Adhesion", 1, 10, step=1)
user_input5=st.slider("Single Epithelial Cell Size", 1, 10, step=1)
user_input6=st.slider("Bare Nuclei", 1, 10, step = 1)
user_input7=st.slider("Bland Chromatin", 1, 10, step=1)
user_input8=st.slider("Normal Nucleoli", 1, 10, step=1)
user_input9=st.slider("Mitoses", 1, 10, step = 1)
inputs=[[user_input1, user_input2, user_input3, user_input4, user_input5,
     user_input6, user_input7, user_input8, user_input9]]
return inputs

inputs = dataset_input(dataset_name)
```

then I split the data and train the model :

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state=1234)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

after that I want to show the predictions of the inputs of the user:

```
y_pred = clf.predict(inputs)
#print(inputs)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
acc = accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test)
print(acc)
```

If I put X_test instead of (inputs), it works fine, But I want the User_input.

Also, when I print (inputs) I get a single prediction value which is a good thing, but I can't show the accuracy score.

Here is the dataset link :
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/breast+cancer+wisconsin+%28original%29

[Here are the variables length after splitting the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOHgH.png)

I would appreciate the help! thank you.

EDIT :
I think I have this problem because my y_pred has 137 values compared to the (inputs) only one value, So I can't show the accuracy.
Unfortunately IDK how to solve this issue .

Answer (score 1):

You are running into that error because your `X` and `y` don't have the same length (which is what train_test_split requires), i.e., `X.shape[0] != y.shape[0]`.

To fix this error:

Remove the extra dimension then transpose `X` by running `X = X.transpose()` to get equal number of samples in `X` and `y`.

Comment: X and y have the same length for me, I tried using X = X.transpose() but didn't work.

Comment: Your X and y have different shape, (9, 683) (683, ), which means `X.shape[0] != y.shape[0]` is True as I stated earlier.

Comment: So, I do this before splitting the dataset or after ?

Comment: You will need to do it before.

Comment: Yes, that's what is expected as I said in the comments.  To solve this, and depending on your data, you will need X and y to be the same length.

Comment: ok , it's the same length now X(683,9) , y(683,).  but I still get the same error showing the accuracy

Comment: Your inputs is a dictionary. You will need to unpack it so that it can match the number of values in y_pred.